# How to show native ads in recylerview using FirestorePagingAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `FirestorePagingAdapter` for showing a list of items in `Recyclerview`. For showing native ads I have to inflate two types of view in my `recyclerview`.Given sample code from 'codelabs' and other sources had an arraylist where all items are loaded once and ads are inserted after a fixed interval. But here my items are too much so I'm using paging library from `jetpack`. How can I inflate different types of layout using `FirestorePagingAdapter`?

Comment: Hi, you got any solution for this? I am having the same query

Comment: @BasimSherif  No, I haven't found any. :(

Comment: Did you guyz find any solution?